# Useful datastructure or Optimize the following case

Tags: powershell, data-structures

I have two files A and B. A contains 17000 records and B will also have approximately 17000 records. I want to compare each record of B with A and all the record's in B that dont match in A should be sent to some other file. I am populating an array with contents of A and then extracting records one by one from B and trying to find it in A using Binary Search.

I am happy with the time taken to search however the step of populating the array with records takes most of the time(80% approx). How can i decrease this time??

I am using powershell for this.

Answer (score 2):

Try the `Compare-Object` cmdlet:

```
$a = Get-Content a.txt
$b = Get-Content b.txt

Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $a -DifferenceObject $b
```

Take a look at the SideIndicator property of the result. '<=' means the entry only exists in $a (ReferenceObject ), and '=>' means the entry exists on $b (DifferenceObject). You can then filter the result using Where-Object and write the InputObject to another file

Comment: Hi shay this executes fine if the file has a small number of records but for my case it takes a lot of time. I want this operation to be done in 10 seconds whereas rite now its taking around 20 seconds...arnd 16 seconds is taken n populating the array...is there any way that can be speeded up??

Comment: PowerShell is not always the bet tool for a specified task, I wonder if sorting the content prior to comparison helps.